# How to calculate variance of an image patch with vectorization

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a 560*560*3 image file, I want to divide the image into many small 8*8 patches, then calculate variance of each patch. What is a vectorized way to calculate variance of each image patch with Matlab or Octave?

Comment: The patches are not 8x8, but 8x8x3, right? How do you define variance considering the three colour components?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nfilter` function:

```
  fun = @var;
  B = nlfilter(A, [8 8], fun);
```

By the way, if you wanted 3x3 image patches, you could use `stdfilt` [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/stdfilt.html) . All that is left is to apply a square on the image:

```
  s = stdfilt(im);
  s = s.*s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mat2cell` and `cellfun`. I am assuming the image is stored in a matrix `M`. And that you want the variance from the mean of the cell and the mean of the cell. Is this an image compression scheme?

```
PatchSize = 8;

%These have the 8x8 patches (although you can change this using PatchSize)
RedPortion = mat2cell(M(:,:,1), PatchSize*ones(size(M,1)/PatchSize, 1), PatchSize*ones(size(M,2)/PatchSize, 1));
GreenPortion = mat2cell(M(:,:,2), PatchSize*ones(size(M,1)/PatchSize, 1), PatchSize*ones(size(M,2)/PatchSize, 1));
BluePortion = mat2cell(M(:,:,3), PatchSize*ones(size(M,1)/PatchSize, 1), PatchSize*ones(size(M,2)/PatchSize, 1));

% The mean(x(:)) takes the mean of the 8x8 cell
RedMean = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), RedPortion, 'uni', 0);
GreenMean = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), GreenPortion, 'uni', 0);
BlueMean = cellfun(@(x) mean(x(:)), BluePortion, 'uni', 0);

% The x - mean(x(:)) takes the variance from the mean of the 8x8 cell
RedVariance = cellfun(@(x) x - mean(x(:)), RedPortion, 'uni', 0);
GreenVariance = cellfun(@(x) x - mean(x(:)), GreenPortion, 'uni', 0);
BlueVariance = cellfun(@(x) x - mean(x(:)), BluePortion, 'uni', 0);
```

Comment: `cellfun` is pretty much using a loop under the hood.  I'm not sure how much faster this would be compared to `for` loops (if at all).

Answer (score 1):

One vectorized approach -

```
PSZ = 8;              %// Patch size
[m,n,r] =  size(A);   %// Get size of image

%// Arrange each patch into columns of a 2D array
ptc = reshape(permute(reshape(A,PSZ,m/PSZ,PSZ,[]),[1 3 2 4]),PSZ^2,[])

%// Perform variance calculations for each column and reshape into a 3D array
out = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@minus,ptc,mean(ptc,1)).^2)/(PSZ^2-1),m/PSZ,n/PSZ,r)
```

Sample run -

Inputs:

```
>> A
A(:,:,1) =
            1            4            5      0.19304      0.39711     0.010979
            6            2            1      0.34164      0.37472      0.57326
            9            0            3       0.9329      0.13111      0.78973
      0.45032      0.37385      0.59497      0.39067      0.43504      0.23537
      0.58247      0.58158      0.96216      0.27322     0.091513      0.44802
      0.68664      0.11612      0.18578      0.15195      0.61463      0.56936

      ....
>> PSZ %//(patch-size)
PSZ =
     3
```

After code run:

```
>> out
out(:,:,1) =
       8.2778     0.091761
     0.066907     0.032665
     ....
```

Verify results for the first patch:

```
    1            4            5    
    6            2            1 
    9            0            3 


>> var([1 4 5 6 2 1 9 0 3]) %// With MATLAB's var function on the first patch
ans =
       8.2778
```

From, the output, we have `out(1,1,1)` is `8.2778`.